# $(\alpha'',\alpha''',\alpha^{IV})=\kappa^5\left(\dfrac{\tau}{\kappa}\right)'$

Tags: differential-geometry

$\alpha$ is a $C^4$ curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with unit speed length, and $\kappa>0$. Then
$$(\alpha'',\alpha''',\alpha^{IV})=\kappa^5\left(\dfrac{\tau}{\kappa}\right)'$$
I've tried so far doing the triple scalar product $(\alpha''\wedge\alpha''')\cdot\alpha^{IV}$ component by component but ended up getting a mess of the fourth derivatives and their indexes. Also, I've tried to develop the RHS but no luck so far. Maybe this involves another equiality for $\kappa$ and $\tau$ (curvature and torsion) of the curve that doesn't come up to my mind. Any hint?

Comment: Component by component? Edit your post to include the Frenet equations and the derivatives expressed in terms of $T,N,B$.

Comment: Component by component I meant, for instance $\alpha'(t)=(\alpha_1(t),\alpha_2(t),\alpha_3(t))$, haven't tried with F-S equations to be honest, gonna try it later :) Thanks!

Comment: Do NOT think about components. Every theoretical question about curves needs Frenet. How else do $\kappa$ and $\tau$ show up, by the way?

Comment: I was thinking about formulas like $\tau=\dfrac{(\alpha',\alpha'',\alpha''')}{||\alpha'\land\alpha''||^2}$ for instance. But those also come from Frenet.